# TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get DataTables to work. After displaying the page the Firefox Development Tools show this error: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a.

Does somebody know the solution to this problem? This is my code:

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- <link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="table_id" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                    <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                    <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just as a note: Had the same error just now, but using datatables 1.10.8 with jQuery v1.11.3 solved the problem. Before I had datatables 1.10.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Sirko mentioned, updated to datatables 1.10.9 & this solved the problem.