# DataTables getting TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj

Tags: jquery, datatables, typeerror

I have this Simple (I guess) DataTable initialization, but I get the following error:

> TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
>   http://localhost/WB/jquery.js Line 539

Here is my code:

```
var table = $('#dt_table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "pageLength": 100,
    "bSortCellsTop": true,
    "order": [[0, "asc"]],
    "dom": '<"top"pfl>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
    "search": "Search:",
    "zeroRecords": "No match",
    "columnDefs": [ { "targets": [1,2,3,4], "orderable": false } ]
});
```

And the HTML for the table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="sconti">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Codice Sconto</th>
            <th>Descrizione</th>
            <th>% Sconto</th>
            <th>% Sconto extra</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='sconto'>
            <td class="text-center"><a class="editable editable-click" data-name="codice_sconto" data-pk="0">0</a></td>
            <td><a class="editable editable-click editable-empty" data-name="descrizione_sconto" data-value="" data-pk="0">Empty</a></td>
            <td class="text-center"><a class="editable editable-click " data-name="p_sconto" data-pk="0">0</a></td>
            <td class="text-center"><a class="editable editable-click " data-name="p_sconto_extra" data-pk="0">0</a></td>
            <td class="text-center"><a class='delete_row' data-pk="0"><i class='fa fa-times red-intense'></i></a></td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I already searched for solutions on SO but I wasn't able to find any because I don't have neither a $.each() loop neither a faulty array/object (like other solutions suggested). So, what I'm doing wrong?

At line 539 of jquery.js I have function isArraylike, and by adding a console.log(obj) I can see that the 'obj' variable is an empty string..

Comment: It would help a lot to see the HTML for this table.

Comment: Which version of jQuery do you use?

Comment: Added. I temporary solved it, by adding 'if ( obj === "" ) { return false; }' in jquery.js isArrayLike() function, but I don't know if it could cause furhter errors

Comment: You could try another version of it. Look at the answer of this [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912605/typeerror-invalid-in-operand-a/30914109#30914109), especially the last comment

Comment: It works with jQuery v 1.11.2, because the isArrayLike function has different implementation. Should I keep using this version? Version 2.1.3 is working too

Comment: Or you could upgrade to dataTables 1.10.7 where I believe this is taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here we're facing seems to be a regression of the fix for preventing JIT error (gh-2145) in IOS. I faced the same problem and quite managed to get it solved by the fix [committed here](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc/commit/485b259e5c02ae7)